# How to hide pages except one in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

here is my pages.toml config

```
[[pages]]
path = "src/features/home.py"
name = "Home"
icon = ""

[[pages]]
path = "src/features/page0.py"
name = "page0"
icon = ""

[[pages]]
path = "src/features/page1.py"
name = "page1"
icon = ""

[[pages]]
path = "src/features/page2.py"
name = "page2"
icon = ""
```

here is my code to run the app:

```
if "current_page" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.current_page = "Home"
    print("change the current page to ::", st.session_state.current_page )
add_page_title()

show_pages_from_config(path='config_files/.streamlit/pages.toml')
```

When I first run the app, I want to show only the Home page and page0. Than I want to programmatically show the pages. Is there a built-in function to do that!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using [st_pages](https://github.com/blackary/st_pages) rather than the built-in multipage functionality. You can hide pages using `st_pages` by passing a list of page names to the `hide_pages` function, e.g.:

`hide_page(["Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3"])`

Comment: is there an option to unhide pages when authenticated.